# Faster algorithms to detect an orange square platform than cv2.FindContours+convexHull?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a drone computer vision project I'm working on with a time limit of .05 seconds. I essentially have to detect an orange square-ish platform with a best-fit square. Right now I'm using openCV backprojection+findContours+convexHull. This works but it's too slow (around .12 seconds). Any other algorithms or better ideas? Should I try implementing the findContour function myself?

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np 
import time 
import math

# creates region of interest histogram
roi = cv2.imread("./images/roi.jpeg")
roi_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

bin_size = 3
roi_hist = cv2.calcHist([roi_hsv], [0, 1], None, [bin_size, bin_size], [0, 256, 0, 256])
cv2.normalize(roi_hist, roi_hist, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)


# returns mask of image after backprojection + thresholding 
def backproject(image, roi_hist):
    image_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    mask = cv2.calcBackProject([image_hsv], [0, 1], roi_hist, [0, 256, 0, 256], 1)
    _, mask = cv2.threshold(mask, 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    return mask


"""
# test image
image = cv2.imread("./images/img3.jpeg")
image = cv2.resize(image, (600, 600))


mask = backproject(image, roi_hist)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
cnt = contours[-1] # selects biggest contour
# hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt) # creates convex hull
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
cntX = cnt[:,0,0]
cntY = cnt[:,0,1]
radii = np.sqrt((cntX - cX) ** 2 + (cntY - cY) ** 2)
min_radius = int(sorted(radii)[0])
print(min_radius)
cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)
cv2.circle(image, (cX, cY), min_radius, (0, 255, 255), 3)
cv2.drawContours(image, [cnt], 0, (255,0,255), 3)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
"""

# for webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    start_time = time.time()
    _, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (800, 600))
    mask = backproject(frame, roi_hist)

    _, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
    cnt = contours[-1] # selects biggest contour
    cnt = cv2.convexHull(cnt)

    M = cv2.moments(cnt)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    cntX = cnt[:,0,0]
    cntY = cnt[:,0,1]
    radii = np.sqrt((cntX - cX) ** 2 + (cntY - cY) ** 2)
    min_radius = int(sorted(radii)[0])

    cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), 2, (0, 255, 255), 3)
    cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), min_radius, (0, 255, 255), 3)
    cv2.drawContours(frame, [cnt], 0, (255, 0, 255), 3)
    cv2.imshow('image', frame)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(end_time - start_time)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is a 
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKwV8.png)

let me point out this is clearly not a square. I am currently just trying to get the contour detection and everything tuned and robust. My end goal is to find the xy-postion and orientation of the best-fit square inscribed in the platform.

Comment: Can you post a sample image? And your current code?

Comment: _Should I try implementing the findContour function myself?_ **NO**

Comment: @MarkSetchell Sure thing. Added code and a sample image.

Comment: @Miki lol yea I did some researching and it is complex af. Really fascinating stuff though. Maybe I should try implementing the convexHull myself since I know the algorithm behind it isn't too complex.

Comment: Your code doesn't appear to be multi-threaded. I have no idea what platform you are using, but even a Raspberry Pi has 4 cores. Maybe you could run acquisition on one core and have 3 cores processing acquired frames in parallel or round-robin to get a good performance improvement...